# Using python to process a chunk of a file every x lines

Tags: python, text-extraction

What I'm trying to do here is to read in **z** lines every line interval **y** from a file **DATA.txt** then execute the function **find** on that chuck of lines. I.e. I want to skip the first **y** lines; read in the next **z** lines; execute the function **find** on those lines just read in; skip the next **y** lines; and repeat for the length of the file (passed into **sys.argv[1]**).

What I have here gives me a load of blank lines for the variable **lines** and I'm not sure why. If need be I can supply the function **find** but I think it's simpler this way.

If anyone wants to suggest a completely different way of doing I'd be just as happy as fixing the existing code as long as I understand what's going on.

EDIT: I was missing a few parens but adding them in did not fix the problem.

```
import sys
import operator
import linecache
def find(arg)
    ...
x=0
while x<int(sys.argv[1]):
   x+=1 
   if mod(x, y)==0:
       for i in range(x,x+z):
           block=linecache.getline('DATA.txt', i)
           g = open('tmp','a+')
           g.write(block)
           linecache.clearcache()
           lines=g.read()
           find(lines)
           g.close()
   else:
       pass
g.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Nit-pick: `linecache.clearcache` won't do anything besides addref'ing the code object. I assume you meant `linecache.clearcache()`.

Comment: @Maimon I think that the use of **linecache** isn't suited for this job. You need a generator or iterator that will run through the file, instead of a heavy function that seems to re-open the file each time a line is required to be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maimon, your initial code is wrong concerning the indexes. And the Andrew's code is wrong too, because he took your code as a start.

See the result of the Andrew's code in which I eliminated the lines concerning **g**:

```
import sys
import operator
import linecache

x=0
y=7  # to skip
z=3  # to print

#g = open('tmp','a+')
while x<23:
    x+=1
    print 'x==',x
    if operator.mod(x, y)==0:
        #curr = g.tell()
        for i in range(x,x+z):
            block=linecache.getline('poem.txt', i)
            print 'block==',repr(block)
            #g.write(block)
            linecache.clearcache()
            #g.seek(curr)
            #lines = g.read()
            #find(lines)

    else:
        pass

#g.close()
```

applied to a file named 'poem.txt' containing 24 lines:

```
1 In such a night, when every louder wind
2 Is to its distant cavern safe confined;
3 And only gentle Zephyr fans his wings,
4 And lonely Philomel, still waking, sings;
5 Or from some tree, famed for the owl's delight,
6 She, hollowing clear, directs the wand'rer right:
7 In such a night, when passing clouds give place,
8 Or thinly veil the heav'ns' mysterious face;
9 When in some river, overhung with green,
10 The waving moon and trembling leaves are seen;
11 When freshened grass now bears itself upright,
12 And makes cool banks to pleasing rest invite,
13 Whence springs the woodbind, and the bramble-rose,
14 And where the sleepy cowslip sheltered grows;
15 Whilst now a paler hue the foxglove takes,
16 Yet checkers still with red the dusky brakes
17 When scattered glow-worms, but in twilight fine,
18 Shew trivial beauties watch their hour to shine;
19 Whilst Salisb'ry stands the test of every light,
20 In perfect charms, and perfect virtue bright:
21 When odors, which declined repelling day,
22 Through temp'rate air uninterrupted stray;
23 When darkened groves their softest shadows wear,
24 And falling waters we distinctly hear;
```

The result is:

```
x== 1
x== 2
x== 3
x== 4
x== 5
x== 6
x== 7
block== '7 In such a night, when passing clouds give place,\n'
block== "8 Or thinly veil the heav'ns' mysterious face;\n"
block== '9 When in some river, overhung with green,\n'
x== 8
x== 9
x== 10
x== 11
x== 12
x== 13
x== 14
block== '14 And where the sleepy cowslip sheltered grows;\n'
block== '15 Whilst now a paler hue the foxglove takes,\n'
block== '16 Yet checkers still with red the dusky brakes\n'
x== 15
x== 16
x== 17
x== 18
x== 19
x== 20
x== 21
block== '21 When odors, which declined repelling day,\n'
block== "22 Through temp'rate air uninterrupted stray;\n"
block== '23 When darkened groves their softest shadows wear,\n'
x== 22
x== 23
x== 24
x== 25
```

I choosed y=7 for the number of lines to be skipped, but the line 7 is printed.

Also, the counting continues with 8, 9, 10... after having printed the 3 lines 7-8-9 (having choosen z=3) instead of continuing with 10, 11, 12... Then the next 3 lines printed are 14-15-16 while it should be the lines after the 7 + 3 first lines that is to say the lines 11-12-13

In fact, if you want to skip 7 lines, then print 3 lines, the lines printed must be:
8-9-10
18-19-20
28-29-30
etc

Am I right ?

### EDIT 1

My solution is:

```
def chunk_reading(filepath,y,z,x=0):
    # x : number of lines to skip before the periodical treatment
    # y : number of lines to periodically skip
    # z : number of lines to periodically print
    with open('poem.txt') as f:
        try:
            for sk in xrange(x):
                f.next()
            while True:
                try:
                    for i in xrange(y):
                        print 'i==',i
                        f.next()
                    for j in xrange(z):
                        print 'j==',j
                        print repr(f.next())
                except StopIteration:
                    break
        except StopIteration:
            print 'Not enough lines before the lines to print'


chunk_reading('poem.txt',7,3)
```

produces:

```
i== 0
i== 1
i== 2
i== 3
i== 4
i== 5
i== 6
j== 0
"8 Or thinly veil the heav'ns' mysterious face;\n"
j== 1
'9 When in some river, overhung with green,\n'
j== 2
'10 The waving moon and trembling leaves are seen;\n'
i== 0
i== 1
i== 2
i== 3
i== 4
i== 5
i== 6
j== 0
'18 Shew trivial beauties watch their hour to shine;\n'
j== 1
"19 Whilst Salisb'ry stands the test of every light,\n"
j== 2
'20 In perfect charms, and perfect virtue bright:\n'
i== 0
i== 1
i== 2
i== 3
i== 4
```

### EDIT 2

The above solution is usable even for very big files that can't be recorded in the RAM.

The following one is usable for files of limited size:

```
def slice_reading(filepath,y,z,x=0):
    # x : number of lines to skip before the periodical treatment
    # y : number of lines to periodically skip
    # z : number of lines to periodically print
    with open('poem.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lgth = len(lines)

    if lgth > x+y:
        for a in xrange(x+y,lgth,y+z):
            print lines[a:a+z]
    else:
        print 'Not enough lines before lines to print'


slice_reading('poem.txt',7,3,5)
```

result

```
['13 Whence springs the woodbind, and the bramble-rose,\n', '14 And where the sleepy cowslip sheltered grows;\n', '15 Whilst now a paler hue the foxglove takes,\n']
['23 When darkened groves their softest shadows wear,\n', '24 And falling waters we distinctly hear;']
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this mistake out, and thank you for your corrections. Not only is this method more accurate, it is also much faster.

Comment: @Maimon Thank you. Was not useful fo your problem, but I inform you of the existence of **islice()**, very interesting functions to cut chunks in an iterable and that may be useful for you in other cases

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: Try the following, I think I have a better idea of what you are trying to do now.

```
g = open('tmp','a+')
while x<int(sys.argv[1]):
   x+=1 
   if mod(x, y)==0:
       curr = g.tell()
       for i in range(x,x+z):
           block=linecache.getline('DATA.txt', i)
           g.write(block)
           linecache.clearcache()
       g.seek(curr)
       lines = g.read()
       find(lines)
   else:
       pass
g.close()
```

Comment: The problem with that fix is that now the code is only executing **find** on one line of data at a time, which it's not meant to do.

Comment: Thank you so much, I very much appreciate your time and you should know your help has gone to a good cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the line `lines=g.read`. It should read `lines=g.read()`

Answer (score 0):

In the "different approach" category, I offer this (line numbers are obviously only for display):

```
  1 """
  2 Reading line lines from DATA.txt, first skip 3 lines, then print 2 lines,
  3 then skip 3 more lines, etc.
  4 """
  5 
  6 def my_print(l):
  7     if (my_print.skip_counter > 0):
  8         my_print.skip_counter -= 1
  9     else:
 10         if (my_print.print_counter > 0):
 11             my_print.print_counter -= 1
 12             print l,
 13         else:
 14             my_print.skip_counter = my_print.skip_size
 15             my_print.print_counter = my_print.print_size
 16             my_print(l)
 17 
 18 my_print.skip_size = 3
 19 my_print.skip_counter = my_print.skip_size
 20 
 21 my_print.print_size = 2
 22 my_print.print_counter = my_print.print_size
 23 
 24 data = open('DATA.txt')
 25 for line in data:
 26     my_print(line)
```

The first way to improve this would be to wrap my_print() with a class (with your x and y as member variables). Then you can get all fancy with generators if you want something truly "pythonic".